# Encoding of the exported jar on Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, encoding

I have many projects that at home work in Mac OS, and sometimes I work on it with Windows.

So, in Eclipse I change the encode of the projects to UTF-8.

But when I export the jars or generate the plugins, and I want to use these jars, it seems the exported jar is not in the encode I want.

To work the exportation I need to externalize the strings, and when I import in other project this lib, wit works well.

Do I need always to externalize strings to export my libs?

Comment: *"it seems the exported jar is not in the encode I want."*   A Zip file, or by extension a Jar file, doesn't have a specific text encoding to my knowledge, since it's a binary format.  The only internal encoding I can think of would be UTF-8 to store the filenames of the contents of the archive. The text files you retrieve from it will have the same encoding as when you put them in.

Answer (score 0):

JAR files do not have an encoding - it is just a ZIP container. If you have resource files they will be copied as they are into the JAR file.

May be you forgot to specify the encoding when loading the resource files containing the externalized strings in your program. In that case the default encoding is used which is different on different platforms.

Therefore if you can change the resource loading source code check if it uses a specific encoding. If you can't change the resource loading source you have to convert the encoding of the resource file.

Answer (score 0):

JARs use the ZIP encoding mechanism and [mandates that](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/jar/package-summary.html):

> In JAR files, all file names must be encoded in the UTF-8 encoding.

The [spec mandates the encoding](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jar/jar.html) of other JAR meta-data (MANIFEST.MF, etc). If a JAR deviates from this, that is a bug.

If you are referring to other resources within the JAR, it is your responsibility as developer to ensure that these files are saved and loaded using the correct encodings.

*There was some discussion that the JAR format would move to a richer format in Java 7/8, but I haven't seen anything concrete.*

Answer (score 0):

I refered to Strings declared inside Java Classes. In this environment the encoding problem occurs... 
To don't occur, I need to externalize the strings. But I don't think this is the solution or if it exists a better approach.

Thanks.